# How can i calculate Total of Grand Total Column from datagridview with Same added_date?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want code to calculate Total with same added date column. Like daily sales report preparation. I have to calculate total of Grand total with same added date in this pic. but using this code i am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[DatagridView image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiruH.jpg)

```
enum GVColumns
    {
        //We make an enum for our GridView columns
        id = 0,
        bill_date,
        bill_no,
        cust_name,           
       sub_total,
        discount,
        grand_total,
        credit,            
        added_by
    }


   private void btnsubtootal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal grandtotalByDate = 0;
        DateTime searchedDate = new DateTime();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSales.SelectedRows)
        {
            var txtDateAddedValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.bill_date].Value.ToString();
            searchedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDateAddedValue); //get our "bill_date" to search
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSales.Rows)
        {
            var txtGrandTotalValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.grand_total].Value.ToString(); //"grand_total" cell value as string
            var txtDateAddedValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.bill_date].Value.ToString(); //"added_date" cell value as string
            var rowDateAddedValue = DateTime.Parse(txtDateAddedValue);

            //check if our dates match
            if (rowDateAddedValue.Date == searchedDate.Date)
            {
                //add "grand_total" values if dates match
                grandtotalByDate += decimal.Parse(txtGrandTotalValue);
            }
        }

        txtNetSales.Text = grandtotalByDate.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: Looks like you did allow the last __empty__ (!) insertion row? It will be all nulls..! You could for example add a check for null on a field and continue if so..

Comment: i didn't get  it can you please clearify it please.. i am new to coding.

Comment: The last row in your image is empty, right. This is the row where the user can add new data. It will be shown when  the dgv property `AllowUSerToAddRows` is true. Since it is empty all Cell.Values are `null`, hence your error. Either loop over one less row or, more robust, text each cell.value for null before using it!